# GCP api exposed key warning on playstore console

Tags: android, android-security

Eventhough i restricted the api keys for a specific app and api's on my GCP account i still get the warning message in the playstore console for my Android app. When will the message go away.

Comment: Did the warning go away..? And can you please post the way, how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you upload a new version of your app?

In the **Next Steps** it says

> Next steps
>
> Update your app using the steps highlighted above.
> Sign in to your Play Console and submit the updated version of your app.
>
> Your app will be reviewed again; if the app has not been updated correctly, you
> will still see the warning. This process can take several hours.